# How to enter several variables to int64_t?

Tags: c++

I have this variables:

```
uint8_t nol_id
char    nol[4]
```

I want to put this information into the next variable:

```
int64_t label : 40
```

so that nol_id will be in the high bits (39,38...) and after char[0],char[1],char[2],char[3].

How can I do that in c++?

Comment: `int64_t label : 40` does not have bits `63,62,...` because it only has 40 bits.  If you meant (39,38,...) then `label = static_cast<int64_t>(nol_id) << 32 | static_cast<int64_t>(nol[0] & 0xFF) << 24 | static_cast<int64_t>(nol[1] & 0xFF) << 16 | static_cast<int64_t>(nol[2] & 0xFF) << 8 | static_cast<int64_t>(nol[3] & 0xFF);`

Comment: @Eljay Minor alternative to avoid 4 casts: `static_cast<int64_t>(nol[0] & 0xFF)` --> `(nol[0] & 0xFFLU)` ...